# Active Model Serializers - undefined method for route helpers

Tags: active-model-serializers

I am building a new application with the `rails-api` gem. I am using `active_model_serializers` to customize my JSON responses. In trying to add a `url` attribute to serializer, I get an error indicating that my resource's route helper methods are undefined. Pertinent code to follow:

```
# Routes
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace :api, defaults: { format: 'json' } do
    namespace :v1 do
      resources :tasks, except: [:new, :edit]
    end
  end
end

# Controller - api/v1/tasks_controller.rb
class Api::V1::TasksController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_task, only: [:show, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /tasks
  # GET /tasks.json
  def index
    @tasks = Task.all

    render json: @tasks
  end

  # GET /tasks/1
  # GET /tasks/1.json
  def show
    render json: @task
  end

  # POST /tasks
  # POST /tasks.json
  def create
    @task = Task.new(task_params)

    if @task.save
      render json: @task, status: :created, location: api_v1_task_path(@task.id)
    else
      render json: @task.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /tasks/1
  # PATCH/PUT /tasks/1.json
  def update
    @task = Task.find(params[:id])

    if @task.update(task_params)
      head :no_content
    else
      render json: @task.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  # DELETE /tasks/1
  # DELETE /tasks/1.json
  def destroy
    @task.destroy

    head :no_content
  end

  private

    def set_task
      @task = Task.find(params[:id])
    end

    def task_params
      params.require(:task).permit(:name)
    end
end

# Serializer
class TaskSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name, :url

  def url
    api_v1_task_url(object)
  end
end
```

As you can see, I am using namespaced routes and have the controllers working. I receive an `undefined method 'api_v1_task_url` error when I try and retrieve a task. I can't figure out why the helper methods aren't included. I'm baffled because every tutorial I find on adding custom attributes like this don't make any adjustments for using these gems (`rails-api` and `active_model_serializers`).

Here is some more relevant information:
   rails version: 4.2.6
   rails-api version: 0.4.0
   active_model_serializers version: 0.10.0.rc5

**Edit**: Here is the output of `rake routes`

```
     Prefix Verb    URI Pattern                 Controller#Action
api_v1_tasks GET    /api/v1/tasks(.:format)     api/v1/tasks#index {:format=>"json"}
             POST   /api/v1/tasks(.:format)     api/v1/tasks#create {:format=>"json"}
 api_v1_task GET    /api/v1/tasks/:id(.:format) api/v1/tasks#show {:format=>"json"}
             PATCH  /api/v1/tasks/:id(.:format) api/v1/tasks#update {:format=>"json"}
             PUT    /api/v1/tasks/:id(.:format) api/v1/tasks#update {:format=>"json"}
             DELETE /api/v1/tasks/:id(.:format) api/v1/tasks#destroy {:format=>"json"}
```

**Edit 2:** Following the suggestion below, I tried:

```
# Serializer
class TaskSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name, :url

  def url
    link(:self) { api_v1_task_url(object) }
  end
end
```

And received a `undefined method 'link'` error.

**Edit 3:** @beauby did point out I was using this method in the incorrect place, however using it correctly still does not create an attribute via a serializer method as I've seen work in numerous tutorials such as this one: http://railscasts.com/episodes/409-active-model-serializers?view=asciicast. It creates a `links` property following the JSONAPI schema, which while helpful and something I will remember, is not what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: What's the output of `$ rake routes`?

Comment: Updated with `rake routes` output

Answer (score 10):

You can add `Rails.application.routes.url_helpers` to your `TaskSerializer` to use url_helpers.

```
  class TaskSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
    include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

    attributes :name

    link(:self) { api_v1_task_url(object) }
  end
```

You can also use `:json` as your ActiveModel Adapter and manually add resource location.

```
  class TaskSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
    include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

    attributes :name, :resource_location

    def resource_location 
      api_v1_task_url(object)
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the `JsonApi` adapter, then you cannot use the `url_helpers` from inside an attribute definition *but* you can use it from inside a `link` definition, as follows:

```
  class TaskSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
    attributes :name
    link(:self) { api_v1_task_url(object) }
  end
```

Comment: This did not work. Error was `undefined method 'link'`. This page: https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/master/docs/general/getting_started.md says that `Rails.application.routes.default_url_options` need to be set, but I'm not having any luck with that this far.

Comment: This should go inside your serializer definition, not inside a method.

Comment: That is precisely where I put it and where it gave me that error.

Comment: Are you certain? Because in your edited question, the call to `link` is inside the definition of the `url` method.

Comment: I see the difference now. You are correct that I can add JSONAPI `links` the way you have it there. However, I was trying to follow the method for creating attributes I have seen in other tutorials, such as this Rails Cast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/409-active-model-serializers?view=asciicast I don't understand why I don't have access to these methods when writing a method of my own, despite these tutorials doing it as I am attempting.

Comment: I should also note, I needed to set `Rails.application.routes.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost:3000' }` to get your `link(:self)` method to work.

Comment: The tutorial you are referring to is intended for AMS v0.8. You are right about setting `default_url_options`.